# not working array list in java my code line which gives me error is persons = new ArrayList()<personInfo>();

Tags: java, arraylist

I am making a address book. For that I've used an 
`ArrayList` but it gives an error

> syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token

Here is my AddressBook class code. I've used three classes. One is personInfo class which contains person info and other is AddressBook class in which I'm currently facing problem and 3rd is main class or drive class. Please help me on this issue

The error points to
 `persons = new ArrayList()<personInfo>();`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AddressBook
{

  ArrayList < personInfo > persons;

  public AddressBook ()
  {
    persons = new ArrayList () < personInfo > ();
  }

  public void addPerson ()
  {
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter Person 
                   Name");
    String add = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter Address");
    String ph = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter Phone Number");

    personInfo p = new personInfo (name, add, ph);

    persons.add (p);
  }

  public void searchPerson (String n)
  {

    for (int i = 0; i < persons.size (); i++)
      {
    personInfo p = (personInfo) persons.get (i);

    if (n.equals (p.name))
      {
        p.print ();
      }
      }
  }

  public void deletePerson (String n)
  {

    for (int i = 0; i < persons.size (); i++)
      {

    personInfo p = (personInfo) persons.get (i);

    if (n.equals (p.name))
      {
        persons.remove (i);
      }
      }
  }
```

Comment: `persons = new ArrayList<personInfo>();`

Comment: Or `persons = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: change your line from --> persons = new ArrayList () < personInfo > (); to persons = new ArrayList < personInfo > ();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Just rewrite

```
persons = new ArrayList<personInfo>();
```

Comment: after applying  persons = new ArrayList<personInfo>(); it gives the following error   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "umar"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at Test.main(Test.java:18)